# VB6 - How to execute a file its path stored in string variable when i click a command button

Tags: shell, vb6

I have a VB 6.0 project and it connected to a database.

I declared `X as string` variable that it will store a file path string that I returned from a field I defined in the database

```vb
X = MyDB.Recordset.Fields("File_Path")
```

X value = c:\blabla\blabla.abc

I had used the following statement and it works perfectly:

```vb
Set wShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
wShell.Open "c:\blabla\blabla.abc"
```

but when I replaced the file path to the variable `X` it does not work.

How to run this file when I click this command button?
Any Idea?

Comment: `but when I replaced the file path to the variable X` - please show how you did that.

Comment: wShell.Open X instead in  wShell.Open "c:\blabla\blabla.abc"

Comment: That should work then. Please double check that X actually contains what you think it does.

Comment: Check if X does not contain any spaces. If it does, use parentheses around the path so the system will know the whole string is one path.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work, you must enclose `X` in parentheses:

```
wShell.Open (X)
```

When you use parentheses when calling a Sub, VB6 will pass the parameter by value instead of by reference.